# Android: How to make a List Item with a buttonview inside and differ the clicks (Whatsapp like)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-button

It receintly came to my atention that Whatsapp introduced phonecalls within their app. I liked the way they added a button inside the list item and are able to distinguish the clock icon clicks from the "rest of list item" clicks. Next you can see the list with its list items.

[image]

My question is how do I differ those clicks. I can ceirtanly add a ButtonView to my list item layout file but when I do that my fragment's OnItemClickListener does not even trigger. If anyone knows how to achieve this, I would really appreciate it.

Again, I'm handling the actual item click events from my Fragment, not from my Activity.

Comment: Pls post your layout xml file of the ListView. And possibly the Adapter getView() too so that we can provide specific code samples.

Comment: please post your Adapter's getView() code. Those click events need to be handled there.